# rabbitmq-erlang-client, using rebar friendly pkg, works on dev env fails on rebar release

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, reltool

I am successfully using the rebar-friendly package of rabbitmq-erlang-client for a  simple Hello World rebarized and OTP "compliant" app and things work fine on the dev environment. I am able to fire up an erl console and do my `application:start(helloworld).` and connect to the broker, open up a channel and communicate to queues.

However, then I proceed to do `rebar generate` and it builds up the release just fine, but when I try to fire up from the self contained release package then things suddenly explode.

I know rebar releases are known to be an obscure art, but I would like to know what are my options as far as deployment for an app using the rabbitmq-erlang-client.

Below you will find the output of the console on the crash:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 18-Dec-2012::16:41:35 ===
    application: session_record
    exited: {{{badmatch,
               {error,
                {'EXIT',
                 {undef,
                  [{amqp_connection_sup,start_link,
                    [{amqp_params_network,<<"guest">>,<<"guest">>,<<"/">>,
                      "127.0.0.1",5672,0,0,0,infinity,none,
                      [#Fun<amqp_auth_mechanisms.plain.3>,
                       #Fun<amqp_auth_mechanisms.amqplain.3>],
                      [],[]}],
                    []},
                   {supervisor2,do_start_child_i,3,
                    [{file,"src/supervisor2.erl"},{line,391}]}, 
                   {supervisor2,handle_call,3,
                    [{file,"src/supervisor2.erl"},{line,413}]}, 
                   {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                    [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,588}]},
                   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                    [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}}}},
              [{amqp_connection,start,1,
                [{file,"src/amqp_connection.erl"},{line,164}]}, 
               {hello_qp,start_link,0,[{file,"src/hello_qp.erl"},{line,10}]},
               {session_record_sup,init,1,
                [{file,"src/session_record_sup.erl"},{line,55}]},
               {supervisor_bridge,init,1,
                [{file,"supervisor_bridge.erl"},{line,79}]},
               {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
               {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]},
             {session_record_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: permanent {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller
```

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments.

`reltool.config`

```
{sys, [
       {lib_dirs, ["..", "../deps"]},
       {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
       {app_file, strip},
       {rel, "session_record", "0.1.0",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib,
         sasl,
         session_record
        ]},
       {rel, "start_clean", "",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib
        ]},
       {boot_rel, "session_record"},
       {profile, embedded},
       {incl_cond, derived},
       {mod_cond, derived},
       {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs
       {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*", "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",
                           "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},
       {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},
       {app, session_record, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, ".."}]},
       {app, hipe, [{incl_cond, exclude}]}
      ]}.

{target_dir, "session_record"}.

{overlay, [
           {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
           {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
           {copy, "files/nodetool", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/nodetool"},
           {copy, "files/session_record", "bin/session_record"},
           {copy, "files/session_record.cmd", "bin/session_record.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/install_upgrade.escript", "bin/install_upgrade.escript"},
           {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},
           {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}
          ]}.
```

Comment: Could you post your `reltool.config` file?

Comment: @kjw0188 I posted the requested config file, the strange thing is that generating the release does not fail and the code that seems to be failing is from amqp_client while opening the connection. I tripled checked all network settings on the rabbitmq server a.s.o. Thanks for your help

Comment: Generating the release just moves files around, so it's possible your release is not including the amqp client, leading to an undefined error.

Comment: Right, I do see the amqp_client on the lib along with other dependencies/apps, furthermore there is a sasl log that shows how the code goes into the amqp_client modules and crashes, I suspect this is an issue with the client code and has nothing to do with the release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `{mod_cond, derived}` to `{mod_cond, all}`.  That means that reltool will not try to be clever about which modules to take from the included applications.  I suspect that your problem is that reltool didn't consider `amqp_connection_sup` to be necessary; you could confirm that by checking whether it's present in `lib/amqp_client-0.8/ebin`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @legoscia worked. 
Here is sample, reltool.config

```
    %% -*- mode: erlang -*-
%% ex: ft=erlang
{sys, [
       {lib_dirs, ["..","../deps"]},
       {erts, [{mod_cond, all}, {app_file, strip}]},
       {app_file, strip},
       {rel, "chat_grabber", "1",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib,
         sasl,
           couchbeam,
         chat_grabber
        ]},
       {rel, "start_clean", "",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib
        ]},
       {boot_rel, "chat_grabber"},
       {profile, embedded},
       {incl_cond, derived},
       {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs
       {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/(?!start_clean.boot)",
                           "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",
                           "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},
       {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},
       {app,couchbeam,[{mod_cond,app},{incl_cond,include},{lib_dir, "../deps/"}]},
       {app, chat_grabber, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, ".."}]}
      ]}.

{target_dir, "chat_grabber"}.

{overlay, [
           {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
           {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
           {copy, "files/nodetool", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/nodetool"},
           {copy, "chat_grabber/bin/start_clean.boot",
                  "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/start_clean.boot"},
           {copy, "files/chat_grabber", "bin/chat_grabber"},
           {copy, "files/chat_grabber.cmd", "bin/chat_grabber.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/install_upgrade.escript", "bin/install_upgrade.escript"},
           {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},
           {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}
          ]}.
```